# Image sets are compact but Domain set is not?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification, compactness, connectedness

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be an arbitary non-empty set and let $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$ be the projections of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on the first and second coordinates respectively . Which of the following statements are true?

$(1)$ If $K$ is compact, then $\pi_1 (K)$ and $\pi_2(K)$ are both compact.

$(2)$ If $\pi_1 (K)$ and $\pi_2 (K)$ are both compact, then $K$ is compact.

$(3)$ If $K$ is connected, then $\pi_1 (K)$ and $\pi_2(K)$ are both connected.

$(4)$ If $\pi_1 (K)$ and $\pi_2 (K)$ are both connected,  then $K$ is connected.

My attempt:-

$\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ can be easily shown to be continous and so $(1)$ and $(3)$ are true.

For $(2)$ and $(4)$

Let $K=\{(x,0) | x\in [-1,1]\setminus \{0\}\}\cup \{(0,y)| y\in [-1,1]\setminus \{0\}\}$

Basically $K$ is union of the line segments $[-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$ corresponding to the $x$ and $y$ axis in the plane.

Claim : $K$ is not closed and not connected.

Proof :- **Not closed.**

$(0,0)\in K'$ (the derived set) but $(0,0)\notin K$ .Hence $K$ is  not closed and so not compact.

**Not connected**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x,y)=x+y$ . Then $f$ is continous.

Now $1 , -1 \in f(K)$

But it can be show $f(x,y)\neq 0$ for any $(x,y) \in K$ . Hence $f(K)$ is not connected since intervals are the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and that means $K$ is not connected.

Is there any quicker argument for this?

Now $\pi_1(K)=\pi_2(K)=[-1,1]$ . So $(2)$ and $(4)$ are false by this counter-example.

Are my works correct? Alternative ideas/examples  will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Other counterexamples: For (2): the closed unit disk minus its origin.  For (4): two concentric circles in the plane

Comment: Aha :) Nice examples. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is just fine! Here is another example that will work for both (2) and (4): the union of two certain right triangles (I mean, full triangles, not just the boundary), from which one removes the hypotenuse:

[image]